# SQLite и Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Существует база данных SQLite, создание таблиц и заполнение данных осуществлялось Visual Studio 2015. Затем была сформирована модель EF6 с использованием библиотеки Data.SQLite.EF6. 
При создании контекста данных получение данных не проходит, не знаю почему :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
            </parameters>
         </defaultConnectionFactory>
         <providers>
              <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
              <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
          </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.data>
           <DbProviderFactories>
                <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
                <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
                <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
           </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
      <connectionStrings>
           <add name="AbiturientBDEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model1.csdl|res://*/Model.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;D:\....\AbiturientBD&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Вот код из модели Entity Framework, который создает контекст данных:

```
public AbiturientBDEntities()
    : base("name=AbiturientBDEntities")
{
}
```

....

```
public virtual DbSet<Абитуриент> Абитуриенты { get; set; }
```

Вот код на C#, который пытается использовать контекст. В объекте obj я не получаю никаких данных. Соответственно, преобразование ToLit() вызывает исключение

```
using (var context = new AbiturientBDEntities())
{
   var obj= context.Абитуриенты;
   var list = obj.ToList();
}
```

Comment: а где у вас `aaa`  объявляется? ( я вижу только `obj`)

Comment: простите, aaa это тот же obj, просто не исправил. 
По поводу абитуриентов: Entity Framework создает этот код
    public virtual DbSet<Абитуриент> Абитуриент { get; set; }

Comment: простите, aaa это тот же obj, просто я не исправил в этом посте. В коде у меня с одним именем. 
Контекст набор сущностей создает сам
public virtual DbSet<Абитуриент> Абитуриенты { get; set; }

Comment: внесите изменения в вопрос, я думаю достаточно оставить только строку соединения, остальной конфиг можно убрать. и да что за путь к бд: *data source=&quot;D:\....\AbiturientBD&quot;*

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Путь к БД я стер, чтобы не показывать его здесь, на самом деле он реальный

Comment: Если оставить только <connectionstring>, возвращается ошибка No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'. 
Если раскомментировать только один провайдер, возвращается ошибка отстутствия фабрики
В общем фабрику тоже раскомментировал, единственное, убрал один провайдер, оставил только второй, ошибка не исчезает
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />

Comment: @SergeyFilippov Я думаю Bald имел ввиду , что не нужно в вопросе показывать весь конфиг. в своем коде конечно оставьте не только connectionstring

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема решилась. Проблема в том, что база данных SQLite создавалась в Visual Studio 2015, которая не формировала системную таблицу sqlite_sequence. Создал БД в SQLite Manager для Firefox, Entity модель сформировалась, данные были получены. Всем спасибо.